# Android textfield elements are tapable, but not editable

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uitest

I am playing around with Xamarin UITest and I have noticed that on my Android device (Samsung S10E, v. 10) Xamarin UITest (v. 3.0.7) when I tap on an entry text element I cannot then enter text inside of that element.

The entry element is focused with the cursor inside of the entryfield and the keyboard is displayed, but no text is entered. To add another level of complexity, my test PASSES and does not FAIL even though the text was never entered.

Here is my code:

```
app.WaitForElement(c => c.Class("UsernameID"));
            Thread.Sleep(3000);
            app.EnterText(c => c.Id("UsernameID"), "Password1");
```

Also, tried this:

```
app.EnterText(c => c.TextField("LoginUserIDEntry"), "oaqa_Clark6_ps");
```

I inserted a thread sleep in case the keyboard was not loading in time for the EnterText call.

The same code on iOS works perfectly fine.

I understand that Xamarin.UITest does not use the soft keyboard. Instead, it injects itself between the soft keyboard and the application and simulates key presses. Whereas iOS actually simulates the presses on the keyboard.

Can anyone tell me if this is a syntax issue, device specific issue, or Xamarin issue?

Answer (score 0):

In order to identify xamarin element you need to use either [`x:Name`  or even `AutomationId` field in shared project xaml.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/uitest/#interacting-with-the-user-interface)

Class will try to find it by Class name in native android or iOS. It's highly unlikely that class names in both platforms are same as you seems to have mentioned in the first code block.

To be generic you should mostly use `Marked` should work UITest projext

```xml
<Entry x:Name="entryXName" AutomationId="entryAutoId" />
```

```cs
app.EnterText(c => c.Marked("entryXName"), "oaqa_Clark6_ps");
//by id
app.EnterText(x=> x.Id("entryAutoId"),"foobarblahblackship");
```

There is whole good documentation here [on official site](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/appcenter/test-cloud/uitest/get-started-xamarin-forms)

You can [check sample](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/blob/master/UsingUITest/UsingUITest.UITests/Tests.cs) as well.

I have learnt that `Thread.Sleep` will block UI main thread,instead you should use `await Task.Delay`